# Is it possible to use AOP/AspectJ to affect StringBuilder

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

Could I use AOP to enforce that every time a StringBuilder is used the first inserted sign would be `!!`.

So if the code below is anywhere in my project:

```java
String sb = new StringBuilder().append("22").toString();
```

`sb` would actually be `!!22`

The example I have is more concerned with logging:

```java
@Component
@Aspect
class LoggingAspect {
    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Around("execution( * com.example..*.*(..) )")
    public Object log(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        this.log.info("before " + pjp.toString());
        Object object = pjp.proceed();
        this.log.info("after " + pjp.toString());
    }
}
```

The problem I have is if it is even possible to define such a *joinpoint* for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. I am not familiar with the syntax that you are currently using. But with AspectJ would be something like:

```java
public aspect InterceptStringBuilders {

    StringBuilder around(StringBuilder target) :
                  call(public StringBuilder append(String)) &&
                  !within(InterceptStringBuilders) &&
                  target(target)
                  {
                      if(target.length() == 0)
                      {
                         target.append("!!");
                      }
                      else if(target.length() == 1 || target.charAt(0) != '!' || target.charAt(1) != '!')
                      {
                         target.insert(0, "!!");
                      }
     
                      return proceed(target);
                 }
}
```

The join point is `public StringBuilder append(String)` and you need the pointcut `target` to expose the StringBuilder so that you can enforce that it starts with "!!". Furthermore, you also need the pointcut `!within(interceptStringBuilders)` to ensure that you do not intercept the calls to the Stringbuilder from the aspect itself.

I guess with the syntax that you are using would be something similar to :

```java
"call(public StringBuilder append(String) && !within(LoggingAspect) && target(StringBuilder)"
```

**A running Example**:

**Main.java :**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append("22").toString());
    System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append("!2").append("!2").toString());
    System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append("!!2").append("!!2").toString());
    }
}
```

**InterceptStringBuilders.aj**:

```
public aspect InterceptStringBuilders {

    StringBuilder around(StringBuilder target) :
                  call(public StringBuilder append(String)) &&
                  !within(InterceptStringBuilders) &&
                  target(target){
                      if(target.length() == 0){
                         target.append("!!");
                      }
                      else if(target.length() == 1 || target.charAt(0) != '!' || target.charAt(1) != '!')
                      {
                         target.insert(0, "!!");
                      }
                      return proceed(target);
                 }
}
```

**Output:**

```
!!22
!!!2!2
!!!!2!!2
```